# R Roxygen2: How to document a function generated by another function?

Tags: r, roxygen2

In my package, I have written a functional which takes a function as input and produce another function. How can I document a function produced via such a procedure?

Below is an illustration: use a functional to convert `sin()` (which takes radian input) to `sind()` which takes input in degree unit.

```
rad2deg <- function(f) {
  force(f)
  function(x) f(x / 180 * pi)
}
```

*Here is some documentation for the function below...*

```
sind <- rad2deg(sin)
```

The `rad2deg` is just my utility functional used by only me and thus not exported nor documented. I only need to export `sind`. But I have no idea how it can be done, as it is not even recognized as a function, and it doesn't even have a explicit argument (of course implicitly it takes the argument of the `sin` function). So, not even the `@param` tag can be used.

Is there anyone who have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It works. The following code generates an Rd file and NAMESPACE directive for the `sind` function.

```
rad2deg <- function(f) {
  force(f)
  function(x) f(x / 180 * pi)
}

#' sin for degrees
#' @param x an angle in degrees
#' @return sin(x)
#' @export
sind <- rad2deg(sin)
```